# Where to enter referral code in Battle Camp?

Tags: battle-camp

I have extra facebook accounts and I signed up with my extra account, did not find any place to enter my referral code. It just shows another referral code where I can invite new people, but no place to enter the current referral I got.

Where can I enter it?